# Compile collada dom library for Android using NDK

Tags: android, dom, android-ndk, pcre, collada

I found out that collada dom has been used and compiled in IceCreamSandwich:  [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/collada/+/android-4.0.4_r2.1).
There are all source files but libpcre and libpcrecpp are required to succesfully run the Android.mk. Those libraries are also present inside ics : [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pcre/+/android-4.0.4_r2). 
However i can't manage to compile libpcrecpp (libpcre compiled : i've got a libpcre.a) with this custom Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir )

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

 GEN := $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcrecpp_internal.h
 $(GEN): $(LOCAL_PATH) /cpcrecpp_internal
    $(hide) cp $(LOCAL_PATH) /config.h.generic $@
LOCAL_GENERATED_SOURCES += $(GEN)

GEN := $(LOCAL_PATH)/pcre_chartables.c
$(GEN): $(LOCAL_PATH)/pcre_chartables.c.dist
    $(hide) cp $(LOCAL_PATH)/pcre_chartables.c.dist $@
LOCAL_GENERATED_SOURCES += $(GEN)
 GEN := $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcrecpparg.h
 $(GEN): $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcrecpparg.h
        $(hide) cp $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcre.h.generic $@
LOCAL_GENERATED_SOURCES += $(GEN)
 GEN := $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcrecpp.h
 $(GEN): $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcrecpp.h
        $(hide) cp $(LOCAL_PATH) /pcre_chartables.c.dist $@
LOCAL_GENERATED_SOURCES += $(GEN)
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++0x  


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=\
    pcrecpp.cc \
    pcrecpp_unittest.cc\
    pcre_dfa_exec.c \
    pcre_exec.c \
    pcre_fullinfo.c \
    pcre_get.c \
    pcre_globals.c \
    pcre_info.c \
    pcre_internal.h \
    pcre_maketables.c \
    pcre_newline.c \
    pcre_ord2utf8.c \
    pcre_refcount.c \
    pcre_study.c \
    pcre_tables.c \
    pcre_try_flipped.c \
    pcre_ucd.c \
    pcre_valid_utf8.c \
    pcre_version.c \
    pcre_xclass.c \
    pcre_chartables.c \
    ucp.h \
    pcre.h \
    config.h\


LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS := pcrecpp.h
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO := libpcrecpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_MODULE := libpcrecpp
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
 LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I get this log when i run ndk-build :

```
jni/Android.mk:26: warning: overriding commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:30: warning: overriding commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:26: warning: ignoring old commands for target `jni'
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for module pcrecpp
Android NDK:   pcre_internal.h ucp.h pcre.h config.h
jni/Android.mk:17: warning: overriding commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:30: warning: ignoring old commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:17: warning: overriding commands for target `/pcrecpp_internal.h'
jni/Android.mk:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/pcrecpp_internal.h'
jni/Android.mk:22: warning: overriding commands for target `jni/pcre_chartables.c'
jni/Android.mk:22: warning: ignoring old commands for target `jni/pcre_chartables.c'
jni/Android.mk:26: warning: overriding commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:26: warning: overriding commands for target `/pcrecpparg.h'
jni/Android.mk:26: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/pcrecpparg.h'
jni/Android.mk:30: warning: overriding commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:26: warning: ignoring old commands for target `jni'
jni/Android.mk:30: warning: overriding commands for target `/pcrecpp.h'
jni/Android.mk:30: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/pcrecpp.h'
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for module pcrecpp
Android NDK:   pcre_internal.h ucp.h pcre.h config.h
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: pcrecpp <= pcrecpp.cc
jni/pcrecpp.cc: In static member function 'static bool pcrecpp::Arg::parse_longlong_radix(char const*, int, void*, int)':
jni/pcrecpp.cc:819:40: error: 'strtoq' was not declared in this scope
jni/pcrecpp.cc: In static member function 'static bool pcrecpp::Arg::parse_ulonglong_radix(char const*, int, void*, int)':
jni/pcrecpp.cc:851:50: error: 'strtouq' was not declared in this scope
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/pcrecpp/pcrecpp.o] Error 1
```

Is this the right process to compile such a library?